# Доступ к scope из директивы. AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, scope

Помогите разобраться.

Есть контроллер. В него приходят данные, все хорошо.

```
function interviewCtrl($scope, InterviewFactory){
    $scope.interview = [];
    InterviewFactory.getInterview().success(function(data){
        $scope.interview = data;
    });
}
```

Создаю директиву:

```
app.directive('ngDatelimit', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope){
            console.log(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

В консоле вижу содержимое скопа, включая объект `interview`. Но не могу получить доступ к `scope.interview`, возвращает пустой объект.

Как получить содержимое уже заполненного `$scope.interview`?

Comment: как вы хотите потом его использовать?

Comment: @Grundy, хотя бы элементарно обработать и вернуть через template

Comment: если просто показать в template - то ничего не надо делать, сразу в шаблоне и использовать. ангуляр сам подставит что надо, когда данные появятся

Comment: @Grundy, это логично. Но что, если мне нужно поработать с этими данными в директиве?

Comment: в данном случае только `$watch` - либо делать вызов сервиса непосредственно внутри директивы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как значение полю присваивается асинхронно, то в момент выполнения метода `link` - значение в большинстве случаев будет еще не заполнено.

В качестве решения можно рассмотреть несколько подходов:

1. [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) - добавить наблюдателя, и когда значение изменится - сделать необходимые действия

   ```
   link: function(scope){
       var unwatch = scope.$watch("interview",function(newValue, oldValue){
           if(newValue != []){ // если значение не пустой массив
               // значит запрос что-то вернул. можно что-то делать
               unwatc();//так как получаем только один раз, нет нужды наблюдать за изменениями дальше, убираем наблюдателя
           }
       });
   }
   ```
2. Вызывать сервис непосредственно внутри директивы, например добавив его в контроллер директивы

   ```
   controller: function($scope, InterviewFactory){
       InterviewFactory.getInterview().success(function(data){
           $scope.interview = data;
       });
   }
   ```
3. сохранить в скопе сам запрос

   ```
   $scope.getInterview = InterviewFactory.getInterview();
   ```

   затем в методе `link` добавить ему функцию success

   ```
   link: function(scope){
       scope.getInterview.success(function(data){
           $scope.interview = data;
       });
   }
   ```
4. использовать фильтр непосредственно во view

Comment: Сделал через $watch. Спасибо за ответ!